# COMET with classic AJAX chat

Tags: php, jquery, chat, comet

I have implemented a chat system using **comet technique**. Here is the link (see 2nd method with ajax) [comet with ajax](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start)

I am using it with 2 browsers and with 2 accounts when i send message with one account, the other receiver receives it with its own name. 
Here is the code:

```
handleResponse: function(response)
{

 $('chat_id_box').innerHTML += '<u class="myId">' + response['name'] + '</u>:&nbsp;&nbsp;<p class="talk">' + response['msg'] + '</p></br>';

},
```

here s controller

```
$filename  = dirname(__FILE__).'./data.txt';
    $name   =   $this->session->userdata('name');
 // store new message in the file
  $msg = isset($_GET['msg']) ? $_GET['msg'] : '';
  if ($msg != '')
   {
  file_put_contents($filename,$msg.$name);
   die();
   }


  // infinite loop until the data file is not modified
   $lastmodif    = isset($_GET['timestamp']) ? $_GET['timestamp'] : 0;
  $currentmodif = filemtime($filename);
     while ($currentmodif <= $lastmodif) // check if the data file has been modified
   {
    usleep(10000); // sleep 10ms to unload the CPU
   clearstatcache();
   $currentmodif = filemtime($filename);
  }

   // return a json array
   $response = array();
   $response['msg']       = file_get_contents($filename);
  $response['name']         =   file_get_contents($filename);
  $response['timestamp'] = $currentmodif;
    echo json_encode($response);
  flush();
```

Suppose if i type **xyz: helo world!**  then in 2nd browser i receive this message as **abc: helo world!**  **abc** and **xyz** are 2 users. What is the problem in the code? I can't understand.
thanks..

Comment: Can you post the full code? We need to understand your code fully to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the session data of the current user as the name but the sender actually isn't the current user. Perhaps you can send the username and the message together to the server?

```
handleResponse: function(response)
{
    $('chat_id_box').innerHTML += '<u class="myId">'+response.user+'</u>:&nbsp;&nbsp;<p class="talk">'+response.msg+'</p></br>';
}
```

## Update

Although this is a little bit late, you can encode your data into JSON. Then, when you use it, you can decode it.

```
<?php
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename));
$response->timestamp = $currentmodif;
echo json_encode($response);
flush();
```

When you write message to the file, you can use this:

```
<?php
file_put_contents($filename,json_encode(array('msg'=>$msg,'name'=>$name)));
```

Comment: @LISON I tried this 
 $name = $this->session->userdata('name');
$msg = isset($_GET['msg']) ? $_GET['msg'] : '';
if ($msg != '')
{
  file_put_contents($filename,$msg,$name);
  die();
}

$response['msg']       = file_get_contents($filename);
$response['name']  = file_get_contents($filename);

bt i cant get value...

Comment: I actually mean that how can i get specific data from file file_get_contents($filename)....

Comment: what should i do if i dont want to use text file and want to use my own data base to store it ......
i have done it and values store in db bt it dont display the result the code it in this site [link]http://jsfiddle.net/azamalvi/CGYWp/1/

Answer (score 2):

you should use this hope will work

```
     file_put_contents($filename, implode(';', array($msg, $name)));
     $response = explode(';', file_get_contents($filename));
     $response[0] is your msg and $response[1] is your name.
```

thanks to **nostrzak**